# Android >4.X : pause an active VPN

Tags: android, openvpn

I use an openvpn client to connect to a vpn. Since this client does not stop my vpn when the screen is blanked, I want to create a service to do that. I thought to build an app with a service and register a broadcast receiver(that waits for the screen on/off event) to this service, but I don't know how to pause a vpn programmatically(I didn't find any info through android api).

Does anyone knows if there's a way to pause/restart the active vpn?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to install [OpenVPN Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn).

Check the first box: **Battery Saver**

[image: OpenVPN Connect]

It works great; only thing is that when combined with the **Seamless Tunnel** option, the phone will not prompt you for incoming whatsapp messages or IMs.